# What happens to charges when a uniform wire is accelerating due to earth's gravitational acceleration?

Tags: charge, acceleration, free-fall

***Let me say this in a simple way. I was just curious to know whether charges experience a pseudo accelerational force in a wire when in freefall. The charges are supposed to feel a pseudo force right?
The charges are infinitely small, but at least they should experience some force because it is in a closed environment(The Wire in freefall)(The wire is not experiencing potential differences)
So do charges move around in a wire in freefall?
Pls don't close this question, I need an answer for this phenomenon***

Comment: For classical physics, if there is no voltage difference on the wire there are no charges, the wire is neutral. If you are thinking of electrons and nuclei you should make it clear in your question. Atoms are also neutral if there is no voltage difference.

Comment: ***Why are you so full of style?***

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I'm sorry I should have added electrons, Please excuse me

Answer (score 1):

If the wire is in free fall, the charges inside also are in free fall. There is no pseudo forces. On the other hand, when the wire in at rest on a smooth surface, there is a (very small) compressive stress due to its own weight. So, theoretically, the equilibium distance between the nuclei is a little different than in free fall. The energy state of the electrons in the bands should also be affected. My guess is that the effect is too small to be detectable.